# 301 redirect with special characters

Tags: htaccess

Trying to do a redirect like:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/tag/blog/alarmforce%20videorelay http://www.mysite.com/blog/tags/tag/alarmforce-videorelay
```

I guess the space is causing the issue. I've tried escaping but it still doesn't redirect properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a "real" space and wrapping it in quotes.  Something like:

```
Redirect 301 "/blog/tag/blog/alarmforce videorelay" http://www.mysite.com/blog/tags/tag/alarmforce-videorelay
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solution did NOT work for me, but this did:

```
RedirectMatch My.*file.*with.*spaces.pdf "http://www.server2.com/My file with spaces.pdf"
```